# Compare intercept of logistics (mixed-effects) model to value other than 0

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, intercept

Is it possible to compare the intercept of a logistic mixed-effects model to a value other than 0?

Specifically, I have two choice alternatives and try to predict choices. My intercept would then tell me whether both options are equally likely (0 in log odds aka .5 in probability). However, I would like to test against another probability and assume, say, that one option is chosen on 3/4 of trials. In other words, I would like a comparison to .75 instead of .5 all while running my same logistic mixed-effects model. Is this possible?

So, what I have in R is:

```
library(lme4)
glmer(choicebehavior ~ trials * group + (1|participant.id), family = binomial, data = df)
```

What I would want is something along the lines of perhaps:

```
## not run
glmer(choicebehavior ~ trials * group + .25 + (1|participant.id), family = binomial, data = df)
```

where I "shift" the entire model to compare to a different baseline.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question is not related to generalised mixed models specifically, but requires an understanding of the logit link function.

In R, [confusingly](https://ro-che.info/articles/2018-08-11-logit-logistic-r), the logit link function is given by `qlogis` and it's inverse the logistic function by `plogis`.

To modify a probability expressed on the log-odds scale (i.e. the output of `glm()` or `glmer()` with `family=binomial()`) where `a` represents the intercept and `B` a regression coefficient which can be extracted from the fitted model using `coef()`:

```
mod <- glmer(choicebehavior ~ trials * group + (1|participant.id), family = binomial, data = df)
a <- coef(mod)[1] #global intercept
B <- coef(mod)[-1] #fixed effect coefficients
plogis(a+B) #probability of outcome given intercept & coefficients
```

To convert any probability, e.g. 0.75, onto the log-odds scale

`qlogis(0.75) #1.098612`

Which can then be added to the fixed effects estimated from a model, such as trials or group in your example:

`plogis(qlogis(0.75)+B)`

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! So then my code might look like this:
`glmer(choicebehavior ~ plogis(qlogis(0.75) + trials * group) + (1|participant.id), family = binomial, data = df)`
with e.g. a significant positive intercept now indicating that the option coded as 1 is chosen more than 75% of the time?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to add anything inside the function. After running the model, the output you want can be obtained by transforming the fixed effect coefficients in the context of your chosen intercept. Are you trying to obtain odds ratios or a probability?

Comment: If you want an _odds ratio_ and `B` is a single fixed effect coefficient from the model (can be extracted using `coef()`), the command is `exp(qlogis(0.75)+B)`. If you want a _probability_ of the outcome the command is `plogis(qlogis(0.75)+B)`

Comment: I believe my above suggestion was wrong, seeing as I would then be mixing up a log odds constant with my normal fixed effects. But so then in conclusion it is easy to convert log odds to odds ratios or probabilities, but it is not so straightforward to test the entire logistic model against a constant other than 0 (in log odds, so .5 in probabilities).
Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @FlamingGoose I have a similar problem as the one presented here, but my model is intercept only: 
`glm(cbind(succ, fail) ~ 1, data = dat, family = binomial)`
I don't have B, so I don't understand how to compare the mean (i.e. intercept) to probability of 0.9 .